# Docker swarm: communication between replicas of the same service

Tags: docker-swarm, docker-networking

I have a Docker swarm of two machines, and started a service with two replicas:

```
$ docker service create --replicas 2 --name myservice --network ingress alpine:latest sleep 1d
```

Now I've got two containers `myservice.1.<some_nonce>` and `myservice.2.<other_nonce>` on different machines that can communicate through the overlay network, as expected.

The problem is how to make the instances discoverable for each other. For example, for `myservice.1` there should be a way to find `myservice.2` without knowing the nonce.

Internal DNS can only resolve the name `myservice` but not a particular task.